# Is there any way to quickly see ALL existing SSIS package event handlers?

Tags: error-handling, ssis

SSIS event handlers are very useful.  Event handlers can be added at the level of the package itself, or for any executable in the package.  This, along with the *Propagate* property, is very useful to allow certain operations to deal with errors in their own way.  For example, a loop can react to an error by recording that "This row with key [whatever] had a problem", carry on with the rest of the rows, and not trigger the package's Error handler, which is saved for more fatal, general errors (e.g. a server goes down).

The number of places there can be an event handler is also a curse.  In Visual Studio, the *Event Handlers* tab is where you can see, add or change event handlers.  It's great if I want to add an event handler to task ExecuteSomeSQL, or sequence container DoSomeThings - or to find the event handlers for these executables *which I already know are there*.

But it's not suited to quickly finding out which executables in the package actually have any event handler.  To do that, I have to click through the executables tree onto *every* executable, and see whether each one has anything under *Event Handlers*.

An alternative view would make this much easier.  Either:

1. Show all existing event handlers in a non-tree way, just as a list.  Package.OnError, Package.OnTaskFailed, (sequence)DoSomeStuff.OnPostExecute, etc...
2. Or, allow the tree view to be filtered to show only executables that have any event handler.

Am I missing something, is there actually already a good way to see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Package Explorer is what you're looking for. It's the last tab for a non-running package.

Every level has "Executables" and an "Event Handlers" section. As you expand either one, you'll see what's listed there.

My sample is a Foreach Loop with a Data Flow Task inside it. The Data Flow has OnError event handler with a sequence container, and an OnPostExecute with an sequence container with a script task inside there. Fortunately, you can't add an event handler on an event handler (you might have been able to in earlier versions).

[image]

Otherwise, I think you're looking at writing custom code to crawl your package.

Comment: Thanks.  That is slightly easier, as it's in the main pane rather than in a drop-down.  Still suffers from the "tree" problem - great to make the structure clear, but not to quickly see all existing handlers.  I'll have to live with it, until a quiet day when I can fiddle about with some custom code (and get over my allergy to XML first...)